# solr index database column name is different from the solr field name

Tags: database, solr, indexing

I want indexing a database with a solr field name different from the column name "TR.nom" :

```
<entity name="id" query="select R.id, R.titre, R.description, TR.nom
                            from Ressource as R
                            join TypeRessource as TR
                            on R.typeRessource_id = TR.id">
<field column="R.id" name="id" />
    <field column="R.titre" name="titre" />
    <field column="R.description" name="description" />
    <field column="TR.nom" name="typeRessource" />
</entity>
```

In the schema.xml :

```
<field name="typeRessource" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Indexing works fine for all fields but not for "typeRessource".

If the field name is the same as the column name I don't have any problems.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can always use AS on your sql query to make the column name match the solr field name
in your case :

```
select R.id, R.titre, R.description, TR.nom AS typeRessource
from Ressource as R
join TypeRessource as TR
on R.typeRessource_id = TR.id
```